# KONG- POSTGRES 9.5 Error: don't know how to auth: 10 during start the KONG

Tags: mapping, connectivity, kong

Here Im trying to connect the KONG with postgresql 9.5 version. Have installed the KONG 2.6.0 and postgresql 9.5 .
Have configured all the things and try to run the KONG using below command

```
kong migrations bootstrap [-c /etc/kong/kong.conf]
```

[image: Ubuntu terminal for kong configurations]

After that below error occur.
Please help me to find the solution for connect the postgres with KONG on ubuntu server.

```
root@kong-gateway:/etc# kong migrations bootstrap [-c /etc/kong/kong.conf] --v
2021/11/17 12:11:45 [verbose] Kong: 2.6.0
2021/11/17 12:11:45 [verbose] reading config file at /etc/kong/kong.conf
2021/11/17 12:11:45 [verbose] prefix in use: /usr/local/kong
2021/11/17 12:11:45 [verbose] preparing nginx prefix directory at /usr/local/kong
2021/11/17 12:11:45 [verbose] SSL enabled on
2021/11/17 12:11:45 [verbose] proxy SSL certificate found at /usr/local/kong/ssl/kong-default.crt
2021/11/17 12:11:45 [verbose] proxy SSL certificate found at /usr/local/kong/ssl/kong-default-ecdsa.crt
2021/11/17 12:11:45 [verbose] SSL enabled on
2021/11/17 12:11:45 [verbose] admin SSL certificate found at /usr/local/kong/ssl/admin-kong-default.crt
2021/11/17 12:11:45 [verbose] admin SSL certificate found at /usr/local/kong/ssl/admin-kong-default-ecdsa.crt
2021/11/17 12:11:45 [warn] ulimit is currently set to "1024". For better performance set it to at least "4096" using "ulimit -n"
Error:
/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/pgmoon/init.lua:211: don't know how to auth: 10
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'auth'
        /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/pgmoon/init.lua:211: in function 'connect'
        .../share/lua/5.1/kong/db/strategies/postgres/connector.lua:218: in function 'connect'
        .../share/lua/5.1/kong/db/strategies/postgres/connector.lua:518: in function 'query'
        .../share/lua/5.1/kong/db/strategies/postgres/connector.lua:286: in function 'init'
        /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/db/init.lua:141: in function 'init_connector'
        /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/migrations.lua:102: in function 'cmd_exec'
        /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/init.lua:88: in function </usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/init.lua:88>
        [C]: in function 'xpcall'
        /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/init.lua:88: in function </usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/init.lua:45>
        /usr/local/bin/kong:9: in function 'file_gen'
        init_worker_by_lua:50: in function <init_worker_by_lua:48>
        [C]: in function 'xpcall'
        init_worker_by_lua:57: in function <init_worker_by_lua:55>
```

Comment: Please copy paste error, don't do a screen shot https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Can you share the configuration relative to postgres ?